# What is meant by "nesting for BSON documents" (in MongoDB)?

Tags: mongodb

From [docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#bson-documents):

> MongoDB supports no more than 100 levels of nesting for BSON documents.

But, what is meant by "nesting for BSON documents"? For example, if I want to implement [Embedding All Comments in One Document](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/storing-comments/#embedding-all-comments) (for threading)

```
{
    _id: ObjectId(...),
    ... lots of topic data ...
    replies: [
        { posted: ISODateTime(...),
          author: { id: ObjectId(...), name: 'Rick' },
          text: 'This is so bogus ... ',
          replies: [
              { author: { ... }, ... },
      ... ]
}
```

and then if I want to access the 101-th levels comment, I can't do this?

`replies_1.0.replies_2.0.replies_3.0.replies_4....0.replies_101`

Comment: Yep, it means that you can't do that (you won't even be able to store that document). But you'll have much bigger problems with that design than mongo's nesting limit :)

Comment: See '@SergioTulentsev comment. Can't you simply add a parent id for replies to existing replies ? This will allow you to store replies as an array.

Comment: Thank you, guys. @Jaco, you talk about [Model Tree Structures with Parent References](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-parent-references/)? I consider this variant also.

Comment: Yes, @kretyak. You could use the Model Tree Structure with Parent Reference. You probably want to store the replies as a separate collection to avoid the document limit of 16MB if you expect many replies.

Comment: Is there a tool out there that counts the number of levels in a given document structure?